# Kafka - consuming from spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I followed [this document](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/kafka-connector-mysql-jdbc/), and It works well. Now I tried to consuming connector data from spark. Is there any reference I can use? Since I use confluent, It's much different from original kafka reference document.

It's some code that I've used so far. The problem is cannot convert record data to java.String. (and not sure that it's right way to consume)

```scala
val brokers = "http://127.0.0.1:9092"
val topics = List("postgres-accounts2")
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount")
//sparkConf.setMaster("spark://sda1:7077,sda2:7077")
sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") 
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record]))

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")


 // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
//val topicsSet = topics.split(",")

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "schema.registry.url" -> "http://127.0.0.1:8081",
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "http://127.0.0.1:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
   "value.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

val data = messages.map(record => {
    println( record) 
    println( "value : " + record.value().toString() ) // error  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    //println( Json.parse( record.value() + ""))

    (record.key, record.value)
})
```

Comment: As you seem to be at the beginning of your work with Spark and its streaming capabilities, let me ask you why you use Spark Streaming not Spark Structured Streaming? See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Since I used jdbc connector from confluent, I think It should be structured straming. isn't it?

Comment: No idea about the jdbc connector from Confluent, but I'm sure you should be using Spark Structured Streaming as the streaming solution in Spark.

Comment: Solved it with take data as record type :)

Comment: Could you then answer your own question and approve? I'm looking forward to seeing the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do sync my value deserializer to below. It will provide proper function and type.

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, record]
```

Comment: There is a new library for handling Avro in Spark Streaming https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS